# using zgrep to find phone numbers in a directory

Tags: linux, unix, grep, zgrep

I need to create a  script that will search for US phone numbers in files that are in a directory that has been passed in as a parameter to your script.  The script must recognize phone numbers in the following formats: (570)555-1212, 570.555.1212, 570-555-1212, and +1.570.555.1212. My script should also be able attempt to minimize false positives.  The script should work on files that are compressed or uncompressed.

The output should be similar to the following.

```
letter.docx: (312)555-1212 570.389.3000

intro.txt: 570-389-3000
```

I have no idea where to start other than

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
zgrep -e 1 -q '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}','[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{4}','+1.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{4}' 
image.dd
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo matches ; else echo "no match found" ; fi
```

Comment: You've chosen the most difficult way possible of solving this problem: writing a complete script and then trying to debug all its problems simultaneously. You will save yourself a ton of trouble if you start small and test each addition thoroughly before moving on to the next one. In this case, you first attempt should have been something like `grep test` to figure out why that's not working before you even try to get phone numbers involved

Comment: Thank you, I will scale down and try again but I must use zgrep.

Comment: You don't even need `grep` yet, because the first problem is "How do I access a directory passed in as a parameter?" Again I really recommend not making any changes until they're needed and you can test them thoroughly. If you use `zgrep` now because you need to search compressed files, I think you'll be stuck later trying to debug why your regex doesn't match anything in `letter.docx`. If you instead use `grep` until you have to deal with compressed files, you'll quickly discover that `zgrep` doesn't work on `docx` files because `zgrep` only supports gzip compression while `docx` uses zip